# search word in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

I've array of strings like `@"fog",@"foggy fod",@"computer",@"lap rop"`.
Now I've string string like `@"i like fog"` now I want to know if my string contains any of the words in my array. Please tell if any of the word in array exist in my string.

**I've tried this so far**

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Keywords"];
NSLog(@"arry %@",array[0]);
int i=0;
for (i=0; i<[array count]; i++) 
{
    if([title containsString:array[i]])
    {
        break;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? what's the result of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is exited before `return true;` is executed because of the `break`. Just remove the break:

```
for (i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    if([title containsString:array[i]])
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it with a `NSPredicate` like this  .

```
NSArray *array = @[@"fog",@"foggy fod",@"computer",@"lap rop"];
NSString *str = @"i like computer";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" %@ contains[cd] SELF", str];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filtered %@",filtered);
```